# Mysql data warehouse SQL Query Help please

Tags: mysql, sql, data-warehouse

I have the following database

```
db: exam_2011
tables: score_01, score_02, score_03.....score_12

db: exam_2012
tables: score_01, score_02, score_03.....score_12
```

the database is the year and the tables are the month;

How can I get the data between 1 July 2011 to 2 February 2012?

Please help to construct the query. The database server is mysql. Thanks. This is not homework or school stuff.

Comment: are these really different DBs / DB servers ?

Comment: Any suggestion to increase the rate? This is on the same database server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have a column named `day` in these tables:

```
select * from exam_2011.score_07
union all
select * from exam_2011.score_08
union all
select * from exam_2011.score_09
union all
select * from exam_2011.score_10
union all
select * from exam_2011.score_11
union all
select * from exam_2011.score_12
union all
select * from exam_2012.score_01
union all
select * from exam_2012.score_02 where day <= 2
```